# iOS: Sync address book with Exchange and contact picture

Tags: iphone, ios, data-synchronization, contacts, exchange-activesync

I sync my iPhone SE with an Exchange server. It retrieves the information and also the contact pictures of the contacts who have them.

With Android, if I added/changed the contact picture by phone, they got also synced to Exchange.

Now with iOS it seems that if I add a contact picture it is not transferred/synced to Exchange. Pretty annoying.

Any fix?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Active Sync on for your Exchange account?

Tap **Settings** > **Mail, Contacts, Calendars**, and select your Exchange account.

Make sure Contacts is turned on for ActiveSync:

[image: iPhone Screenshot]

Adapted from [this Apple Document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201729).

Comment: Yes, of course it is enabled. Other data (like phone number) seems to get synced but not the contact pictures (but they seem to be synced from Exchange to iPhone but not the other way)